# PHP/SQL QUERY - syntax error, unexpected '{' But when removed the query doesn't work

Tags: php, sql

```
<?

$string = '<?php 

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","#","#");
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
  }

$location = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$live = "Scotland";

mysql_select_db("#", $con);
// Line 77 below
mysql_query("UPDATE order SET location='{$location}' WHERE live='{$live}'"); 

?>';


$my_file = 'data.php';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
fwrite($handle, $string);

?>
```

When I try the code above I get this error when trying to write to the data.php file:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in
>   /home/#/public_html/write.php on line 77

I have tried removing the Apostrophes (') from around the {location} and {live} but then the query does not work.

Can anyone help me with this, thanks

Comment: What's the point of generating php scripts like that? How about proper string syntax escaping, PHP string expression escaping, and database context escaping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are attempting to make some sort of auto code making script.

Looks like you have already come across the issue of the quote marks.

The issue you seem to have is that the variables are being interpreted while the string is being generated rather than on the other side. Something like the following may at least resolve one of the issues you are having:

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","#","#");
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
  }

$location = \$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$live = "Scotland";

mysql_select_db("#", $con);
// Line 77 below
mysql_query("UPDATE order SET location='{$location}' WHERE live='{$live}'"); 

?>
EOT;

$my_file = 'data.php';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
fwrite($handle, $string);
?>
```

Additionally this will still not compile at the other end, you will need to escape the "$" on all the variables you are using (like \$con and \$live)

(code untested)

To address your actual issue however try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE order SET location=\'{$location}\' WHERE live=\'{$live}\'");
```

(escaping the quote marks)

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE order SET location=".$location." WHERE live=".$live);
```

Comment: There's no error but the query does not update the database on data.php

Comment: check if $location is able to retrieve any data

Comment: I echo'd $location and it shown my IP, I have double checked the db info by doing the query manually like 

set location='1' where live='Scotland' and it updates

Comment: Try doing a query from inside the code to check if your db connection works. See if it's able to retrieve data.